# Error Google Auth Uploading Video to YouTube

Tags: android

We use YouTube V3 API to upload videos in android. We're using oauth2 authetication for devices in order to allow our app to upload videos to YouTube accounts. But when we authentication for device with new account it shows error-

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty:null
>   android.accounts.Account.(Account.java:48)com.google.android.gms.auth.zzg.getToken(Unknown
>   Source)com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown
>   Source)

We need to authentication for device with new account without creating UI interface. we can only authenticate device with programmatically.

Does anyone has had this issue before? How did you solve it? Do you have ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you added `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission on app `manifest.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

**manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

**Also you many need to check [GET_ACCOUNTS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#GET_ACCOUNTS) runtime permission:**

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(context, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)) {

    } else {
        // Check
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, new String[{Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS}, 101);
        }
}
```

**Read more about [permission group](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#perm-groups):**

- [GET_ACCOUNTS was moved into the CONTACTS permission group in Android 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33125068/1283715)

Comment: For android version 6.0 and above you have to check runtime permission,

Comment: For debugging your issue open device settings/app permission and enable Contacts permission for you app, and check if you still see this issue or not?

Comment: We need to check runtime permission for android version 6.0 but we run app for android version 5.0 and below